# SQL how to select for accounts with 2 or more counts?

Tags: sql, oracle

Problem case is made-up with similar approach of what I want.

I'm wanting to get data on if a customer has ordered the same item multiple times (2 or more). I want the details of each order to be separate, but if they've ordered the same product twice or more, I just want to see the rows twice and can cut off the rest.

Currently, I get rows and rows of the same customer.

I know you can do COUNT and GROUP BY but what I'm actually wanting is slightly different (bit difficult to list everything that I've done).

Example case

Lets say I'm looking at 3 tables joined together

1. customer's details (CUSTOMER)

- customer account, title, name, dob, gender, age, order id

2. delivery details (DELIVERY)

- customer account, order id, country, state, city, suburb/town, street name, street number, unit number, post code

3. purchase details (ORDER)

- customer account, order id, product id, quantity, product price

I need customer account and name, order id, delivery suburb, product id

- product id range of 5 - 10 inclusive
- customer's name starts with J

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER.customer_account,
    CUSTOMER.customer_name,
    CUSTOMER.order_id,
    DELIVERY.suburb,
    ORDER.product_id

FROM CUSTOMER
    LEFT JOIN DELIVERY
        ON CUSTOMER.customer_account = DELIVERY.customer_account
        AND CUSTOMER.order_id = DELIVERY.order_id
    LEFT JOIN ORDER
        ON CUSTOMER.customer_account = ORDER.customer_account
        AND CUSTOMER.order_id = ORDER.order_id

WHERE
    product_id >= 5
    AND
    product_id <= 10
    AND
    SUBSTR(customer_name, 1, 1) = 'J'
```

Lets say the output I get is (* will be removed)

| customer_account | customer_name | order_id | suburb | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACC0000000000001 | JOHNATHAN | 000001 | A | 6 |
| ACC0000000000001 | JOHNATHAN | 000007 | A | 6 |
| ACC0000000000001 | JOHNATHAN | 000012 | A | 6 |
| ACC0000000000001 | JOHNATHAN | 000020 | A | 9 |
| ACC0000000000002 | JACOB | 000025 | B | 7 |
| ACC0000000000002 | JACOB | 000028 | B | 7 |
| ACC0000000000002 | JACOB | 000029 | B | 7 |
| ACC0000000000003 | JAYLEN | 000035 | C | 10 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000040 | C | 10 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000048 | C | 8 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000050 | C | 8 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000059 | C | 6 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000068 | C | 6 |
| ACC0000000000005 | JASON | 000080 | A | 9 |
| ACC0000000000005 | JASON | 000088 | A | 9 |
| ACC0000000000005 | JASON | 000090 | A | 9 |
| ACC0000000000006 | JAMES | 000098 | K | 6 |
| ACC0000000000006 | JAMES | 000106 | K | 6 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000112 | T | 6 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000117 | T | 7 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000126 | T | 7 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000133 | T | 6 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000139 | T | 5 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000148 | T | 7 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000155 | T | 7 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000167 | T | 6 |
| ACC0000000000008 | JORDAN | 000172 | L | 9 |
| ACC0000000000008 | JORDAN | 000180 | L | 9 |
| ACC0000000000008 | JORDAN | 000186 | L | 9 |
| ACC0000000000008 | JORDAN | 000188 | L | 8 |

Output I want is

| customer_account | customer_name | order_id | suburb | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACC0000000000001 | JOHNATHAN | 000001 | A | 6 |
| ACC0000000000001 | JOHNATHAN | 000007 | A | 6 |
| ACC0000000000002 | JACOB | 000025 | B | 7 |
| ACC0000000000002 | JACOB | 000028 | B | 7 |
| ACC0000000000003 | JAYLEN | 000035 | C | 10 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000040 | C | 10 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000048 | C | 8 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000050 | C | 8 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000059 | C | 6 |
| ACC0000000000004 | JAYLEN | 000068 | C | 6 |
| ACC0000000000005 | JASON | 000080 | A | 9 |
| ACC0000000000005 | JASON | 000088 | A | 9 |
| ACC0000000000006 | JAMES | 000098 | K | 6 |
| ACC0000000000006 | JAMES | 000106 | K | 6 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000112 | T | 6 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000117 | T | 7 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000126 | T | 7 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000133 | T | 6 |
| ACC0000000000007 | JORDAN | 000139 | T | 5 |
| ACC0000000000008 | JORDAN | 000172 | L | 9 |
| ACC0000000000008 | JORDAN | 000180 | L | 9 |
| ACC0000000000008 | JORDAN | 000188 | L | 8 |

My thought was doing something like ROWNUM/FETCH for specifically each, but wasn't really sure if that's the right approach nor how to use it...

Comment: Please post sample data as separate tables and desired output for this sample data. It's hard to decouple your current output into the original data to make your code reproducible and to reuse it for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROWNUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY` in following way to achieve this.

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER.customer_account,
    CUSTOMER.customer_name,
    CUSTOMER.order_id,
    DELIVERY.suburb,
    ORDER.product_id
FROM CUSTOMER
    LEFT JOIN DELIVERY
        ON CUSTOMER.customer_account = DELIVERY.customer_account
        AND CUSTOMER.order_id = DELIVERY.order_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_account, order_id) AS row_num
                  FROM ORDER
                  WHERE (order_id, customer_account) IN (
                    SELECT order_id, customer_account
                    FROM ORDER
                    GROUP BY order_id, customer_acccount
                    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
                  )
               ) AS LIMITED_ORDER
        ON CUSTOMER.customer_account = LIMITED_ORDER.customer_account
        AND CUSTOMER.order_id = LIMITED_ORDER.order_id
WHERE
    product_id >= 5
    AND
    product_id <= 10
    AND
    SUBSTR(customer_name, 1, 1) = 'J'
    AND
    row_num <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

- To use a quoted identifier for `ORDER` as it is a reserved word;
- To change from `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` for the `ORDER` table as the join is required rather than being optional;
- To use the `COUNT` analytic function to count the frequency for each `customer_account` and `product_id` pairing;
- To use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to number the rows in each `customer_account` and `product_id` pairing so that you can restrict the output to two rows per pairing.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT c.customer_account,
       c.customer_name,
       c.order_id,
       d.suburb,
       o.product_id
FROM   CUSTOMER c
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT o.*,
                COUNT(order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_account, product_id) AS cnt,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY customer_account, product_id
                  ORDER BY order_id
                ) AS rn
         FROM   "ORDER" o
         WHERE  product_id BETWEEN 5 AND 10
       ) o
       ON     c.customer_account =  o.customer_account
          AND c.order_id         =  o.order_id
          AND o.cnt              >= 2
          AND o.rn               <= 2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN DELIVERY d
       ON     c.customer_account = d.customer_account
          AND c.order_id         = d.order_id
WHERE  c.customer_name LIKE 'J%';
```